# DataTable Reformat

Tags: r, data.table

```
    d1=data.frame("Student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
    "Score"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,2,3),
    "Grade"=c(5,6,7,3,4,5,2,4,7,8,9),
    "Class"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),
    "School"=c(100,100,100,100,100,100,92,92,81,81,81))


    d2=data.frame("Student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
"Q1"=c(0,1,0,1),
    "VX"=c(0,0,1,1),
    "A"=c(5,3,2,7),
    "B"=c(7,3,4,7),
    "C"=c(7,4,4,8),
    "D"=c(7,5,4,9),
    "Class"=c(1,1,2,1),
    "School"=c(100,100,92,81))
```

I have data 'd1' and wish for data 'd2' with rules:

Student: Just Student from d1

Q1: if Score from d1 ever equalled to 2 for a Student from d1, this equals to 1. If not it equals to 0.

VX: if Score from d1 ever equalled to 3 for a Student from d1, this equals to 1. If not it equals to 0.

A: equals to the first/minimum Grade from d1 for a Student

B: if Score from d1 equalled to 2, then put the Grade JUST BEFORE that happened. If not then put the last/maximum Grade. Importantly the first Grade can not equal to 2 so there is no worry of missing data.

C: if Score from d1 equalled to 2, then put the Grade when that happened. If not then put the last/maximum Grade

D: if Score from d1 equalled to 3, then put the Grade when that happened. If not then put the last/maximum Grade

Class: Just the Class from d1

School: Just the School from d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `data.table`, we can do. :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d1)[,.(Q1 = as.integer(any(Score == 2)), 
        VX = as.integer(any(Score == 3)), 
         A = first(Grade), 
         B = if(any(Score == 2)) Grade[which.max(Score == 2) - 1] else max(Grade),
         C = if(any(Score == 2)) Grade[which.max(Score == 2)] else max(Grade),
         D = if(any(Score == 3)) Grade[which.max(Score == 3)] else max(Grade)), 
     .(Student, Class, School)]


#   Student Class School Q1 VX A B C D
#1:       1     1    100  0  0 5 7 7 7
#2:       2     1    100  1  0 3 3 4 5
#3:       3     2     92  0  1 2 4 4 4
#4:       4     1     81  1  1 7 7 8 9
```

---

Using `dplyr` here can be a little bit advantageous here in terms of typing since we can refer to previously created `Q1` and `VX` column.

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>%
  group_by(Student, Class, School) %>%
  summarise(Q1 = as.integer(any(Score == 2)), 
            VX = as.integer(any(Score == 3)), 
             A = first(Grade), 
             B = if(Q1) Grade[which.max(Score == 2) - 1] else max(Grade), 
             C = if(Q1) Grade[which.max(Score == 2)] else max(Grade), 
             D = if(VX) Grade[which.max(Score == 3)] else max(Grade))
```